# Cannot send information to dialog box; "Office.context.ui.addHandlerAync is not a function"

Tags: javascript, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to send information to a dialog box in an Outlook web-add in.

```
var url = window.location.origin+'/dialog.html'
var dialog
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url2,
       function (asyncResult) {
           dialog = asyncResult.value;
           dialog.messageChild('message')     
           });
```

Which opens a dialog box and tries to send information to the dialog which has this Javascript:

```
Office.onReady().then(()=> {
        Office.context.ui.addHandlerAsync(
            Office.EventType.DialogParentMessageReceived,
            onMessageFromParent);         
    });

function onMessageFromParent(arg){
    console.log(arg.message)
    document.getElementById('ID').style.display = 'none';
}
```

However, that just gives me the error:

```
TypeError: Office.context.ui.addHandlerAsync is not a function
```

When I run `console.log(Office.context.ui)`, I get:

```
OSF.DDA.UI.ParentUI
[[Prototype]]:Object
closeContainer:function(){ … }
displayDialogAsync:function(){ … }
openBrowserWindow:function(){ … }
__proto__:Object
```

As you can see, there is not a `addHandlerAync` function within `Office.context.ui` but the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) says to use it.

What is going wrong here? Thanks

Comment: Can you `console.log(Office.context.ui.addHandlerAsync())` ? Is it a nonfunction or is it undefined?

Comment: It is a non function. It just gives the error `TypeError: Office.context.ui.addHandlerAsync is not a function`

Comment: Have you checked it? It would be great to know this for sure.

Comment: Yes, when I run `console.log(Office.context.ui.addHandlerAsync())` It just gives me that error. Do you think this could be because I am running an old version of the API? Thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry, I've meant `console.log(Office.context.ui.addHandlerAsync)`. It will either yield undefined or some object.

Comment: `console.log(Office.context.ui.addHandlerAsync)` returns undefined.

Comment: So it does not exist at all. Unfortunately I'm not experienced with office-js, so I cannot contribute further to answering this at this point, but this may be a valuable information.

Comment: I also don't seem to be able to send information from the dialog to the host either. When I try to do it using the method on Microsoft's website I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventHandler')` in the Chrome console.

Comment: Deleted my answer because I didn't notice you are working with Outlook. I'll see if I can find out what MailBox requirement set supports the `addEventHandler` method.

Comment: I'm getting help. In the meantime, can you confirm that the `onReady`method that is calling `addHandlerAsync` is being loaded in a page in the _dialog_, not the task pane? Also could you sideload the manifest here: https://kepengtestapp.azurewebsites.net/manifest/AzureOutlook.xml and see if it works in your environment?

Comment: Also, are  you working on a Windows computer or a Mac?

Comment: OK, I no longer get the `addHandlerSync is not a function` error; I am not sure what happened as I don't think I changed anything. However, I have hit another problem in that the `Office.ready()` in the dialog is being callled AFTER `dialog.messageChild` so the dialog cannot recieve the information. (Information needs to be sent to the dialog as soon as it opens). I can make it work with the `setTimeout()` function but this doesn't seem very robust and causes a delay. Is there a way I can make `messageChild` wait for the `Office.ready` in the dialogbox to be called?

Comment: Would you like to share your code again so we can see how it's implemented. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I look at your add-in. Its taskpane.html is not completed yet and the JavaScript is not included. However, I manually load the dialog page in the debugger and I confirm that your code in dialogbox.html is working. I can see Office.context.ui.addHandlerAsync is available in the Office.onReady handler. Would you like to fix your add-in and double check it's working?

Comment: Hi, I have removed all of the 'taskpane' related html and js as it is not needed for this add-in. The add-in displays the dialog box when the send button is pressed so it only needs the 'commands' and 'dialogbox' related html and js. After the dialog box opens I would like to send information to the dialogbox.